# Looking for a better way to achieve this fixed scroll experiment

Tags: html, css

```
<section class="section">
  <div class="section__clip">
    <div class="section__content">
        <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Experiment: http://codepen.io/AgustinLarzabal/pen/OpNLvR

What i'm trying to achieve is to replicate this scrolling effect, but without repeating the content in each .section

Anyone can help me?

Comment: I like that effect. *upvoted*

Comment: Are you having differnt content in each section if so look into `z-index:` on each of the sections but would need to add inline though

Comment: Some content would be the same in all sections, thats why i'm trying to achieve this without repeating content.